# Disable-web-security in Chrome 48+

Tags: google-chrome, security, same-origin-policy

I have a problem with the `--disable-web-security` flag. It is not working in Chrome 48 and Chrome 49 beta on Windows.

I've tried killing all of the instances, reboot and run Chrome with the flag first of all, tried different machines as well. In the beta I can see the warning popup ("You are using unsupported flag.."), but CORS is still being enforced. Public version seems to ignore the flag completely.

There seems to be no news or people reports about that, so it might be a local issue. 
Will be grateful for help or any related info.

Comment: Responsible developers don't disable web security https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/128511

Comment: @gman: It's a simple and reliable solution for a problem that you sometimes have during development. Just remember to close that browser instance again. No need for FUD.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

## Update 2021-10-18

As of Chrome 95, on MacOS and Windows, `--disable-site-isolation-trials` remains a required flag in order to disable web security, so the command-line arguments to Chrome seen below are still valid. (Some of the arguments are not formally supported by Chrome, as it will warn you.)

To test whether you've successfully launched Chrome with web security disabled, run the snippet in **Web Security Test** at the bottom of this post.

## Update 2020-04-30

As of Chrome 81, it is mandatory to pass *both* `--disable-site-isolation-trials` and a non-empty profile path via `--user-data-dir` in order for `--disable-web-security` to take effect:

```sh
# MacOS (in Terminal)
open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials

# Windows (from "Run" dialog [Windows+R] or start menu in Windows 8+)
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=%TMP%\temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials
```

*(Speculation) It is likely that Chrome requires a non-empty profile path to mitigate the high security risk of launching the browser with web security disabled on the default profile. See* **`--user-data-dir=` vs `--user-data-dir=/some/path`** *for more details below.*

Thanks to [@Snæbjørn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220627/sn%c3%a6bj%c3%b8rn) for the Chrome 81 tip in the comments.

---

## Update 2020-03-06

As of Chrome 80 (possibly even earlier), the combination of flags `--user-data-dir=/tmp/some-path --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials` *no longer disables web security*.

It is unclear when the Chromium codebase regressed, but downloading an older build of Chromium (following ["Not-so-easy steps" on the Chromium download page](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)) is the only workaround I found. I ended up using Version 77.0.3865.0, which properly disables web security with these flags.

---

## Original Post 2019-11-01

In Chrome 67+, it is necessary to pass the `--disable-site-isolation-trials` flag alongside arguments `--user-data-dir=` and `--disable-web-security` to truly disable web security.

On MacOS, the full command becomes:

```sh
open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir= --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials
```

### Regarding `--user-data-dir`

Per [David Amey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509189/1727828), it is still necessary to specify `--user-data-dir=` for Chrome to respect the `--disable-web-security` option.

#### `--user-data-dir=` vs `--user-data-dir=/some/path`

Though passing in an empty path via `--user-data-dir=` works with `--disable-web-security`, it is not recommended for security purposes as it uses your default Chrome profile, which has active login sessions to email, etc. With Chrome security disabled, your active sessions are thus vulnerable to additional in-browser exploits.

Thus, it is recommended to use an alternative directory for your Chrome profile with `--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-sesh` or equivalent. Credit to [@James B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215140/james-b) for pointing this out in the comments.

### Source

This fix was discovered within the browser testing framework Cypress: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951

## Web Security Test

Run this snippet to confirm that this solution actually disabled web security in Google Chrome:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
  iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const canAccessIframeDocument = !!iframe.contentDocument;
    document
      .querySelector(
        canAccessIframeDocument ? ".security-disabled" : ".security-enabled"
      )
      .classList.remove("hidden");
  });
  // To ensure the `load` event always fires, only set iframe src after the
  // event listener is attached.
  iframe.src = "https://google.com";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* Web security should normally be enabled, so this is colored green, despite
   the objective of this solution to disable it. */
.security-enabled {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgreen;
}

.security-disabled {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<h1>Web Security Test</h1>
<p>
  This test attempts to access the inner contents of a cross-origin iframe,
  which is normally disallowed.
</p>
<p class="security-enabled hidden">
  Web security is enabled. The cross-origin iframe document could not be
  accessed.
</p>
<p class="security-disabled hidden">
  Web security is disabled. The cross-origin iframe document was
  successfully accessed.
</p>
<iframe class="hidden">
  Iframes are not supported.
</iframe>
```

Comment: Just because a value isn't required to make it work doesn't mean it's a good idea.  Running the command you give will open your default Chrome profile, with established sessions to your email / bank / whatever, but no web security to keep those accounts from being compromised by malicious sites.

Comment: Good point @JamesB. I've rolled your insight into the answer.

Comment: On my Mac with Chrome 81, this command worked: `open -na Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp` I obtain an alert complaining about the `~/chromeTemp` dir, but works

Comment: @David though I didn't get the Chrome 81 update yet (it's not available in Settings), web security was not disabled when I ran your command-line. The warning about `~/chromeTemp` happens because the tilde `~` does not get expanded to your home directory as you might expect. This is verifiable by putting an `echo` before the entire command-line and seeing that the `~` is still printed out.

Comment: @mxxk Chrome 81 is the beta (develop using the beta version is a way to anticipate to future changes that may break your site). I have been trying different command lines and that was the only one that worked in my case, but I've observed that for other people the previous commands still works... It's weird

Comment: Stuck on Enterprise Chrome 79-ish and I can confirm the security flags still work.

Comment: I can confirm that `--user-data-dir=C:\tmp\some-path --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials` work in Chrome 81 on windows 10

Comment: Good find @Snæbjørn. Just confirmed that these flags work on Chrome 81 on MacOS, _and_ that both `--disable-site-isolation-trials` and a non-empty `--user-data-dir` are both required for web security to be properly disabled. Updated the answer.

Comment: `--disable-site-isolation-trials` is not necessary but a value for `user-data-dir` is (tested on Chrome 89/Win) - see Irrech's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @wortwart. Perhaps Chrome 89 made `--disable-site-isolation-trials` unnecessary in this case. I'm still on Chrome 88 (MacOS), and can confirm that `--disable-site-isolation-trials` still needs to be present. Will update the answer after confirming Chrome 89+ behavior.

Comment: This helps. Thank you. I tried --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials on Windows. Chrome reports unsupported command line arguments for both --disable-web-security and disable-site-isolation-trials. So I removed those two arguments, it works, and  the error "origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy" is gone now when I open a react app in a local folder. I am using the latest Chrome Version 93.0.4577.82.

Comment: Latest 2021 versions of Chrome didn't accept this parameters anymore. Just show "unsupported command line flags". Finding alternatives.

Answer (score 89):

I'm seeing the same thing. A quick google found this question and a [bug on the chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690). It seems that the `--user-data-dir` flag is now required.
Edit to add [user-data-dir guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md)

Comment: Thank you, it works! Empty --user-data-dir doesnt work in beta anymore, though. One should provide a value to user data for both flags to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still had trouble, as I never implemented this before, so if people are still confused after reading the above, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 61):

Mac OS:

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=`

UPD: add `=` to `--user-data-dir` because newer chrome versions require it in order to work

Comment: Since [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690) was fixed, you'll need to specify a user-data-dir so:

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/some/dir`

Comment: For Chrome Version 50+ for Mac Users. Close all opened chrome first and run the below command

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""`

Comment: Note: A banner should appear that states "web security is disabled". If this banner doesn't appear you need to make sure to force quit chrome before running the command (right click quick launch icon -> quit -> re-run command).

Comment: *Please note*! From Chrome version 80 the `--user-data-dir=""` is not working anymore with `--disable-web-security`.
You need to put a real path like `--user-data-dir="/tmp/temppropfile"`

Answer (score 33):

On OS X, to open a new Chrome window - without having to close the already open windows first - pass in the additional *-n* flag. Make sure to specify empty string for data-dir (necessary for newer versions of Chrome, like v50 something+).

```
open -na /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""
```

I found that using Chrome 60+ on Mac OS X Sierra, the above command no longer worked, but a slight modification does:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_sess_1" --disable-web-security
```

The data directory path is important. Even if you're standing in your home directory when issuing the command, you can't simply refer to a local directory. It needs to be an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks! Google Extension,  Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: didn't work for me but this did!

Answer (score 26):

The chosen answer is good, but for those who are still struggling with what they are talking about(your first time dealing with this issue), the following worked for me.

I created a new shortcut to Chrome on my desktop, right clicked it, and set the "Target" field to the following,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/chromedev"
```

The directory can be anything you want, I decided to make an empty folder called chrome dev in my C: directory. It has nothing to do where chrome is installed on your computer. It's just a fluff type thing.

This link also has clear directions for other OSes. [How to disable web securityin Chrome](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/09/disable-same-origin-policy/)

Answer (score 15):

The version 49.0.2623.75 (64-bit) is not in beta anymore.

The command to fix the CORS issue is 

`google-chrome-stable --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: Do I have to this everytime?

Answer (score 10):

Install This Chrome-plugin for Disable-web-security in Chrome::

" Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * "
[link Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) or you can google above plugin if you want.

it is very easy to enable and disable the security with this plugin.

Comment: Link has expired

Answer (score 4):

From Chorme **v81** the params `--user-data-dir=` requires an actual parameter, whereas in the past it didn't.
Something like this works fine for me

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="\tmp\chrome_test"
```

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome Version 50+ for Mac Users. Close all opened chrome first and run the below command

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""
```

The above will work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Mac, using Safari is a good alternate option for local development purpose and the feature is built into the browser (so no need to add browser extension or launch Chrome using bash command like [open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""].

To disable cross origin restriction using Safari (v11+): From menu click “Develop > Disable Cross Origin Restriction”.

This does not require relaunching the browser and since its a toggle you can easily switch to secure mode.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal put these:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/chromedev"
```

Answer (score 2):

**For MacOSX**

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_sess_1" --disable-web-security
```

**For Windows 10+**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

Answer (score 1):

As of the date of this answer (March 2020) there is a plugin for chrome called [CORS unblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino) that allows you to skip that browser policy. The 'same origin policy' is an important security feature of browsers. Please only install this plugin for development or testing purposes. Do not promote its installation in end client browsers because you compromise the security of users and the chrome community will be forced to remove this plugin from the store.

Answer (score 0):

It working for me.
Try using this..it will help you out..

`c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"`

Comment: It didn't work for me without the quotes on the URL "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application> .\chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```