# Chrome 49 plus --disable-web-security

Tags: google-chrome, security

Today (Mar, 15, 2016) chrome stopped working with the --disable-web-security flag. I have tried the following options described in various posts:
1) Kill all instances of Chrome.exe in the windows task manager.
2) add the --use-data-dir flag, [there is a current post regarding this, but the answers there do not work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432749/disable-web-security-in-chrome-48-and-49)

Here is my script I am using:

> start chrome.exe --disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content  --use-data-dir=c:/temp/chrome_dev

Chrome opens under this script with the disable security warning but localhost cross domain calls still fail:

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this today too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have solutions that are using `--disable-web-security`.

Finally I found solution. Now chrome just will accept it if you set `--user-data-dir` together.
You will have different instances when you use it.
Try it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"
```

Comment: I tried this, copied the batch script directly, no changes and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Instead of using an arbitrary directory, you can omit the value of user-data-dir.  The following works for me on Windows 10 with Chrome 49: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

Comment: doesn't make much sense but seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Works on version 56. Thanks

Comment: Works on version 59 (with an empty --user-data-dir), even though the alert is still displayed. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

For linux

```
google-chrome  --user-data-dir=”/var/tmp/Chrome” --disable-web-security
```

I suggest a temp directory

Comment: Kept getting `browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(108)] Failed to launch GPU process.
Created new window in existing browser session.` when I ran the command **without** the `--user-data-dir` flag. Your answer fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam11p
Based on your answer, I have created an alias.
`alias google_chrome_security_disabled='google-chrome --user-data-dir="/home/rudy/.config/google-chrome_security_disabled" --disable-web-security'`

Answer (score 5):

Just for OS X user, this worked for me (on El Capitan): `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="<some-dir>"`

Also works on Yosemite 10.10.5. Please note that --user-data-dir may no longer be left empty. You have to specify some dir.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, this does ```open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""```

Comment: Recently, this hasn't been working for me without specifying an existing `user-data-dir` directory, which needs to be cleared on every session. That also resets all history, user preferences, logins, ... every single time. This being extremely irritating, I have now started using this Chrome extension instead: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

**This doesn't work anymore, since Chrome 80. You have to specify a non-default `--user-data-dir` to make it work now.**

Original answer:

You can use your existing data dir, if you don't want to create a new one.

So on Linux the command to start unsafe Chrome will be something like this:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/home/<your username>/.config/google-chrome --disable-web-security
```

But don't use this Chrome instance for anything except development or debugging, since it's open for a **vast** amount of web attacks.

Answer (score 2):

> This works with chrome 61 too for me -

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not disable web security**. [You're opening your accounts to attacks and your local files to being stolen](https://games.greggman.com/game/dont-disable-web-security/).

Instead use a simple web server. It will take you all of 2 minutes to install and use. [Here's one with a gui](https://greggman.github.io/servez/), and [here's several more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver) that run from the command-line

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have found a permanent solution for this disable web security issue.

step 1: create 1 chrome app shortcut on desktop and rename it anything like "disabled-security.exe"

step 2: right click on icon and go to properties => change target input box to something like following eg. and save it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials --user-data-dir=c:\chromeSession
```

step 3: launch this app, it will work fine as expected

Note: everytime you need to clear folder "c:\chromeSession" before opening this app