# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: for node js api

Tags: node.js, angular, header, meanjs

I am building an angular2 app with node as server,below is my api..

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/getcategories
```

When i called the abpove api,i got the following error in my console,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/auth/getcategories. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am not sure about the next step to solve the above issue,can anyone suggest help......

Comment: do you host the application from the same server with the api?

Answer (score 0):

Server must return set of [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). In this particular case you should add to response following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Of course on production environment allowing all origin hosts (`*`) probably is not a good idea.

If you cannot add header to server's response, you can disable checking CORS headers by running Chrome with [`--disable-web-security` and `--user-data-dir`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36021258/5508756) flags.