# Launch Google Chrome on Mac with multiple flags

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am trying to launch Chrome on mac machine from terminal. I want to pass 2 flags:
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security --allow-access-from-files
It seems to be picking up the first flag but not the second.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLopz.png)

Comment: What Google Chrome version are you using? I think you should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432749/disable-web-security-in-chrome-48-and-49

Comment: Chrome Version: 54

Comment: thx jvarela. I don't have any issues launching Chrome with the --disable-web-security flag. My problem is I can't launch Chrome with both flags. THere does not seem to be an issue in Chrome, but with Mac I am getting problems