# CORS still working after disabling browser web security

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, cross-domain

So I have been testing a website using Selenium, specifically a page with a credit card form embedded in an iframe. I want to access the content of said iframe but due to CORS I get the error message:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "<url>" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I made a quick google search and realized you can bypass CORS using the "--disable-web-security" flag, so my code now looks like the following:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER"), options=options)
```

Surprisingly, the CORS exception keeps on popping and I'm currently stuck on how to go from here. I really do have to access the iframe's content, there isn't a workaround for this.

Since I was confused as to why this didn't work, I replicated the problem with another website, in this case *Amazon*, which functions similarly (credit card form embedded in an iframe). I ran the code with web security enabled and I get the same CORS error, as expected. But then I disable web security, exactly as mentioned before, and it works! I can now access the iframe.

I also downgraded to an older version of Chrome (86) from the current most stable (88) and nothing happens again. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

So now I'm wondering - why isn't the flag working for the first scenario I mentioned? Is there a chance the first website is forcing the browser's web security or something related? I'm not an expert in web development so any input on this would be valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, all I needed was to add `--disable-site-isolation-trials` and a non-empty `--user-data-dir` along with `--disable-web-security` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432749/disable-web-security-in-chrome-48)

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding these flags to my Chrome launcher fixed my CORS issues:

```
 --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

Pls note, this only turns warnings off, this is definitely not a CORS *solution*