# Angular - Every request is being blocked by CORS

Tags: angular, api, cors, integration

I'm making an angular 12 application with a java back-end for my university.
I was testing angular's http client but I can't make any request because it's being blocked by CORS.
First, I tried making a POST request to my back-end server, but no luck.
Angular Code:

```js
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:9080'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router:Router) { }

  login(user:User) { 
    this.http.post(`${API_URL}/login`, user, {observe:'response'}).subscribe(result => { 
      console.log(result)
    })
  }
```

[The response was this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViUBK.png)

So, I searched and found that this is most server-side, and even though I can make requests normally in Insomnia/Postman, I tried configuring cors on my server.xml.

But then I had the idea to try and consume external APIs.
I tried making a GET Request to Google, only to get this back:

[Response from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Wwb.png)

And this is occurring with every external API, So I don't think the problem is server-side, but rather with Angular, but I couldn't find any solution that wouldn't say the problem is server-side, but it can't be since I can't make any request to any website, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it seems like your Backend and Frontend are on the same origin, it is in fact not the case

> These are not same origin because they use different ports:
> http://example.com:80
> http://example.com:8080

> Two URLs have the same origin if the protocol, port (if specified), and host are the same for both.

Fixing CORS is always done server-side. Basically the Browser doesn't allow you to make requests from scripts of a different location than your where your frontend is hosted for security reasons. [Read in detail here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

For develop you may disable the Browser CORS check. You can download Browser extension to do so or use chrome flags.
[Read here about the flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58658101/13087977)

```
"--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-sesh", "--disable-web-security"
```

Comment: I see, thanks! If I were to deploy this application to a production server (we were thinking about heroku), that would mean this would be fixed automatically if the server (like google, for example) has the correct headers, right?

Comment: If you configure it correctly, yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy. Do not use wildcard which would defeat the purpose of CORS (XSS prevention)